# How do you stop ui objects being covered when a Date picker selector pops up in swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

How would I move two buttons from the bottom of the screen to the top of a datepicker when it appears when the user goes to enter their birthday? I know there’s code to make UI items move when a keyboard shows up, in fact that’s already in my code:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo else {return}
    guard let keyboardSize = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue else {return}
    let keyboardFrame = keyboardSize.cgRectValue
    let animationDurarion = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! TimeInterval
    UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDurarion, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.backButton_constrant.constant += keyboardFrame.height
        self.nextButton_constrant.constant += keyboardFrame.height
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification){
    guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo else {return}
    guard let keyboardSize = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue else {return}
    let keyboardFrame = keyboardSize.cgRectValue
    let animationDurarion = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! TimeInterval
    UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDurarion, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.backButton_constrant.constant -= keyboardFrame.height
        self.nextButton_constrant.constant -= keyboardFrame.height
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
```

I’m just wondering how I’d do the same, but this time moving the two buttons when the date picker pops up, basically, is there an observer for date pickers?

[Here’s what my app looks like to make it a bit more understandable](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15GZ1y1DczSSBYCYkdFdASWPxt0bqJ1-P/view?usp=drivesdk)

Thanks

UPDATE: FULL CODE:

import UIKit

```
class birthday_createAccountViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    var email = String()
    @IBOutlet weak var birthday_input: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var backButton_constraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var nextButton_constraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    private var datePicker: UIDatePicker?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.birthday_input.delegate = self
        birthday_input.underlined()

        datePicker = UIDatePicker()
        datePicker?.datePickerMode = .date
        birthday_input.inputView = datePicker
        datePicker?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(birthday_createAccountViewController.dateChanged(datePicker:)), for: .valueChanged)


        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboard(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboard(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboard(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @objc func dateChanged(datePicker: UIDatePicker){

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
        birthday_input.text = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
    }


    @objc func keyboard(notification: NSNotification){
        let rect = ((notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as AnyObject).cgRectValue)
        let keyboardHeight = rect?.height

        if notification.name.rawValue == "UIKeyboardWillShowNotification" {
            if UIDatePicker.isEditing == true { //change this for your picker
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
                    self.backButton_constraint.constant += keyboardHeight!
                    self.nextButton_constraint.constant += keyboardHeight!
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                }
            } else {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
                    self.backButton_constraint.constant -= keyboardHeight!
                    self.nextButton_constraint.constant -= keyboardHeight!
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                }
            }
        } else {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
                self.backButton_constraint.constant -= keyboardHeight!
                self.nextButton_constraint.constant -= keyboardHeight!
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You have the code. What is the problem now?

Comment: @RajeshKumarR No, that’s an example for how I did it to make buttons move up when the keyboard appears, I wondering how I would do the same for when a datepicker appears, as shown in the video via the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add Observers like you did for  different ocations

```
private func setObservers() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillChange(sender:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillChange(sender:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillChange(sender:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame, object: nil)       
    }
```

***1.- UIKeyboardWillShow
2.- UIKeyboardWillHide
3.- UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame***

So the observers will run background while the user performs actions 
//this piece of code is from one of my projects us it as example

```
 // Métodos que se ejecutan cuando aparece o desaparece el teclado
    @objc func keyboardWillChange(sender: Notification) {
        print(sender.name.rawValue)

        // Se almacena el rect del teclado, el origen en xy su ancho y su alto
        let rect = ((sender.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as AnyObject).cgRectValue)
        let keyboardHeight = rect?.height

        if sender.name.rawValue == "UIKeyboardWillShowNotification" {
            if Uipcikerdate.isEditing == true { //change this for your picker 
                print("se está editando tokenfield")
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
                    self.topAnc.isActive = false
                    self.botAnc.isActive = false
                    self.topAnc = self.interface.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: -(keyboardHeight!))
                    self.botAnc = self.interface.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -(keyboardHeight!))
                    self.topAnc.isActive = true
                    self.botAnc.isActive = true
                    self.interface.layoutIfNeeded()
                }
            } else {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
                    self.topAnc.isActive = false
                    self.botAnc.isActive = false
                    self.botAnc = self.interface.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)
                    self.topAnc = self.interface.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor)
                    self.topAnc.isActive = true
                    self.botAnc.isActive = true
                    self.interface.layoutIfNeeded()
                }
            }
        } else {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
                self.topAnc.isActive = false
                self.botAnc.isActive = false
                self.botAnc = self.interface.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)
                self.topAnc = self.interface.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor)
                self.topAnc.isActive = true
                self.botAnc.isActive = true
                self.interface.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, will those observers work with a Ui Date Picker or just for the keyboard?

Comment: yes they will, i already update my answer to make it easy for you

Comment: Ah, thank you, I tried it out and I got the error: value of type UIDatePicker? Has no member ‘tokenfield’ when changing the first line of the if statement.

Comment: 'tokenfield' is a UIText of my project change what you need to do is 
if sender.name.rawValue == "UIKeyboardWillShowNotification" {
            if Uidatepicker.isEditing == true {
set the constraints

Comment: I changed it just to ‘if UIDatePicker.isEditing == true{‘ and it has the error ‘type UIDatePicker has no member ‘isEditing’; did you mean ‘isEnding’?’

Comment: @Nathan isEditing means you're editing that field is a swift mehotd but you need to add his protocol that might be the error: UITextFieldDelegate
like this class CodiPaymentVC: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, URL_SessionDelegate {

Comment: I got to be honest, I’m newer to swift and I have no clue what that means, sorry. I have to edit a Delegate class?

Comment: @Nathan to add a protocol go all the way up your code class, and just bellow of 'import' like this import UIKit: you will see your class name like this : class CodiPaymentVC: and you have to add UITextFieldDelegate you need to separate them with ,

Comment: Yeh, that was already there to start with I’m afraid, so I don’t think it’s that, I’ve updated my question with my full code.

Comment: @Nathan what's your "@IBOutlet for your picker date"?

Comment: Never mind, I was being stupid and I was using the actual datepicker var in the statement when I was meant to be using the actual UITextField, stupid mistake on my part. Thank you for all your help, I’ll mark it as the answer :)

Comment: yeah i was about to finish the code an re-posted you're welcome

Comment: Please change `sender.name.rawValue == "UIKeyboardWillShowNotification"` to `sender.name == NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow`. Avoid hardcoding such string names.